# How does Ruby handle undeclared variables as opposed to php?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In php, I can comfortably write:

```
if (x > 100) 
{ 
   method(); 
}
```

knowing that if x doesn't exist, my program will treat it as a small bump in the road and keep going.

I'm used to php's ultra-lax variable typing and undeclared handling, and wondering what the rules of Ruby are in relation to this.

What is Ruby's default action when you try to evaluate something that isn't declared?

And if I can pepper this in too... does null, zero, and false equal the same thing in Ruby?
Would

```
if(!x)
{
  puts 'works'
}
```

puts?

I know these are very simple questions, but either they're too obvious for me to catch or I'm using the wrong search phrases.

Comment: It's a fair question, but why not just try out?

Comment: I'm about 10 minutes in to Ruby. I'm still learning syntax.

Comment: 1.9.3p194 :004 > if(x<10){puts 'yay'}

1.9.3p194 :005?>

Comment: I don't know what to interpret from this irb.

Comment: @Pekka웃: The "just try it out" approach is subject to all sort of externalities, special cases, and undefined/unspecified behaviors. Knowing the specified and guaranteed behavior (if any) is quite valuable. You should have enough experience with odd and inconsistent browser behavior to know the pitfalls of just trying it out to see what happens :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Ruby will complain if you use a variable you have not decalred.
2. In ruby you usually don't enclose an `if` in `{` and `}`, you put an `if` and end it with `end`.
3. `false` `nil` and `0` are different things. Your code will complain that `x` is not defined and will only `puts` if `x` is `false` or `nil`
4. In ruby to check if a value is `nil` you use `nil?` like so `if !x.nil?`

Comment: Thank you! You probably saved me an hour and an unmeasurable heap of confusion.

Comment: What about an array index?

If I have S[0]=0, would if (S[1]) cause an error just the same as an undeclared variable?

Comment: "... and will only puts if x is false" - I'm pretty sure it will output if x is nil as well.

Comment: @PinnyM Correct. Sorry for that! And LBg thank you for the edit

Answer (score 1):

Starting from last question: In ruby, zero is not treated as false, the only falsy values are: `nil` and obviously `false`. Everything else is a "true" value.

Attention: I will use instance variables because it's not really normal there's a change for a local variable not to have been instantiated.

So why this wont work

```
if @x > 100 
  method()
end
```

Because `>` in ruby is actually a method call so if `@x` is nil (undefined variable) it will raise a `NoMethodError` because nil does not have that method defined.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass
```

So what you can do in your condition is to first ensure `@x` has a value like this:

```
if @x && @x > 100 
  method()
end
```

Comment: `nil` is not the value of undefined variables. Undefined local variables are undefined and trying to read from them causes an exception. Undefined global and instance variables (`$x` and `@x`) are indeed initialized to `nil` when read.

Comment: Actually local variables doesn't make any sense to check if they exist. Because you only use them inside a method so you can always ensure it exists.